# Lightweight and fast Browser for Windows 7

Tags: windows, web-browser

I'm using Windows 7 64 Bit OS with 4GB RAM. I had tried all the major browsers, I don't want to install all browsers instead I want the one which is best for me. My Mozilla Firefox is using 450 MB normally, in many times it goes beyond 800 MB. Google Chrome hangs most of the time on my PC. IE is dead slow. Can any one tell me a good browser to go with with a small footprint?

Comment: Why is 450 MB a problem? You have 4000 mb! Today browsers consume a lot of memory, as a lot of apps.

Comment: In single tab it consumes 450 MB , If i open multiple tab i immediately goes beyond 800 MB

Comment: With firefox and twenty tabs opened, it uses only 650 mb. And I don't see the problem unless you are using photoshop also.

Comment: Have you updated to the latest IE version (11)? Its speed has been improved very much. What processor are you using?

Comment: Welcome to  Software Recommendations! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements. For example; What features other than *low memory usage* do you want; ie is text only okay? - that'll be *WAY* lower memory usage. Do you want tabbing? etc. etc.

Comment: I'd say [Lynx](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lynx_%28web_browser%29) comes with a very small footprint. But I doubt you'll like it (*Lynx* is a text-only web browser). I mention this to give you some background on what Nick refers to: you need to name your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Whether this would suit you or not you could try the portable version of Google Chrome or Firefox from [here](http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/google_chrome_portable) or [here](http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/firefox_portable).

- Pretty lightweight I guess
- Fast
- Just like your average everyday browser (just portable)

Try them out first and see if this is what you're looking for. :)

Answer (score 1):

My biggest recommendation is [Midori](http://midori-browser.org).

Midori is a modern, lightweight web browser based on Google Chrome's engine. I use it from time to time, and it is very easy to use.

Comment: To be precise, Chrome doesn't use the Webkit engine anymore. They forked it to a new project called [Blink](http://www.chromium.org/blink).